Can one formalize the prevalence of the Big Five systems of reverse math?
Simpson's systems of second order arithmetic turn out to be five in
number; to simplify notation let's denote them A, B, C, D, E.  What
seems to be an empirical observation is that most theorems in
classical analysis "revert" to one of the five systems, meaning of
course that they are equivalent (over A = RCA$_0$) to the defining
property of the system.
Can this empirical fact be made into a
theorem somehow?  I am thinking of something along the lines of the
classification of finite simple groups, where a consequence of the
classification is the observation that almost all groups fall into
four specific infinite families (the latter observation is of course a precise mathematical statement rather than merely an empirical observation).

How about some links to show what ABCDE are?

Isn't the possibility of such a "theorem" clearly refuted by the Reverse Mathematics Zoo?

This question sees the zoo as analogous to the sporadic groups.  @FrançoisG.Dorais

But the Zoo is infinitely large whereas there are only 26 sporadic groups. I don't think that's a legitimate comparison.

Nonetheless, the experts in the field do talk about the prevalence of the Big Five and the exceptionalism of the Zoo.  My question is whether this observation can be formalized somehow.  @FrançoisG.Dorais

Isn't it just formalized by the fact that many of the central mathematical theorems are in fact reversed to one of the big five? The preponderance of them do fit in the big five. (And if one doesn't think so, then indeed there is no phenomenon to formalize.)

Damir Dzhafarov and I have pondered this question on and off over the course of the last 15 years.  A paper was almost written, which I will dig up and try to push into an answer.
